# how to assign different value to a column for different rows

Tags: ruby, activerecord, migration

For example, there is a table like following:
Column_A Column_B Column_C

1. I want to add a column D using ruby migration
2. I have a function getColumnDValue(columnC). This function can get the value of column D based on the column C value
3. I want to assign different values to column D based on the column C value.

How to do these????

I've checked the Update_All and Update. However, it seems they are not useful for my case.
Or at least, I don't know how to use these methods to achieve my purpose.

Comment: I have added the 'activerecord' tag under the assumption that you are working with Ruby on Rails. If this is not correct, please clarify. I do not understand what _'checked the "Update_All" and "Update"'_ means; it sounds like you're using some GUI management tool for some RDBMS? Or do you mean that you have looked at methods with those names? You will need to provide more details if you want help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to set the value of d the usual way, like so: `myobject.d = 5`. Based on the value in c, d will be saved with the correct value.

This could be accomplished with a `before_save` filter, where you set a new value for d.

You could also overwrite the setter method for d:

```
def d=(value)
  write_attribute(:d, getColumnDValue(value))
end
```

With the first method, the filter, your object will carry the "invalid" value until saved. If you overwrite the setter, the new value will be written to the object immediately. It's up to you to decide which method fits you best.